# How to prevent excel macro from pasting empty rows

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am trying design a macro in excel 2007. Here is what I need it to do:

When I enter an ID into a specific cell and run the macro, it will search for that ID in column A of a different workbook and autofilter. Then I need it to copy that data and paste it into the first workbook. My code is working, however when it is pasting a ton of extra rows beneath my data. How can I make it only copy and paste data and not empty rows? Here is my code:

```
Sub Medications()
    '
    ' Medications Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
    '

    Range("B1").Select
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "I:\Pharmacy\MTMP\2013\Master Lists\CMR Medication List.xlsx"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Member ID"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Workbooks("Standardized Format Spreadsheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Demographics").Range("B1").Value
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Standardized Format Spreadsheet.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Detailed Medication List").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("CMR Medication List.xlsx").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Sheets("Demographics").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to avoid selecting items whenever possible. You can use set a workbook to an object and access it through that.

The reason you are getting extra cells when you copy/paste is because you are selecting every cell and then copying. I suggest using only the used range so you don't pick up any extra cells.

```
Sub Medications()
    Dim CMR_Wkbk As Workbook
    Dim SFS_Wkbk As Workbook

    Set SFS_Wkbk = Workbooks("Standardized Format Spreadsheet")
    Set CMR_Wkbk = Workbooks.Open("I:\Pharmacy\MTMP\2013\Master Lists\CMR Medication List.xlsx")

    Range("A1").Value = "Member ID"
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SFS_Wkbk.Sheets("Demographics").Range("B1").Value
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=SFS_Wkbk.Sheets("Detailed Medication List").Range("A1")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    CMR_Wkbk.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Sheets("Demographics").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
```

`Cells.Select` is selecting the entire content of the worksheet. I don't know, obviously, what you sheet looks like, but try selecting only the `CurrentRegion` - the equivalent of what is highlighted when you click in a cell and press Ctrl-A:

```
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Copy
```